# SystemDateToLocalDate inside SQL Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, sql, automationstudio

I know the function SystemDateToLocalDate is not available inside SQL but i would like exactly that feature inside an SQL query to convert the Date records of data_views (which are CST Central Standard Time) to the dates in a specific timezone with daylight savings (CET - Central European Time and CEST Central European Summer Time).

I didnt found an easy way to do it and stumbled upon various [T-SQL date functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

What i was trying to do is writing SQL Cases that would work like this:

Compare the data of the dataview with:

- lower/earlier than the Last Sunday of March 02:00:00 in CET tranformed to
  CST

  - ==> Dateadd Hours 7 to the dataview time
- greater than or equal to the Last Sunday of March 03:00:00 CEST tranformed
  to CST  AND less or equal to the last Sunday of October 02:00:00 CEST
  transformed to CST

  - ==> Dateadd hours 8 to the dataview time
- You will then have problems because the timeperiod from 02:00:00 to
  03:00:00 could have +7 or +8.
- greater than less or equal to the last Sunday of October 02:00:00 
  transformed to CEST

  - ==> Dateadd hours 7 to the dataview time

You could do it with an SSJS and **[SystemDateToLocalDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDateTimeSystemDateToLocalDate.htm)** but i dont believe that this can handle million of rows as fast as SQL. Especially when the activity is limited to 30min execution time.

**Does somebody has an easy or working idea?**

---

If you think i got something wrong in the logic or orthography please also leave a comment or directly edit the post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice solution and I will post the solution when i have spare time.
It has to do with the t-sql command AT TIME ZONE.

Just seen an answer to that question on linked-in that has just been posted: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/its-timezone-finally-real-convert-function-salesforce-jack-hobbs/

It is the solution i found a month ago but hadn't had spare time to post it since then.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/103994)

Comment: I am the author of the question and found a solution that i will post when i have time.